# In Genexus, Know in runtime is Android or IOS

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

In Genexus, how to know if is compiling for Android or IOS in Smart Device?

Example:

A procedure:

```
If platform = ‘IOS’
   &Variavel = 1
Else if platform = ‘ANDROID’
   &VARIAVEL = 2
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know at complie time, but you can check in runtime.

You can use the `DeviceType` property in `ClientInformation`

```
&deviceType = ClientInformation.DeviceType
if &deviceType = SmartDeviceType.iOS
    &variavel = 1
else // if &deviceType = SmartDeviceType.Android
    &variavel = 2
endif
```

See more info in the official documentation: [ClientInformation external object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31271,ClientInformation%20external%20object,)

Comment: Great idea. How did I not think of this before?
Thank You.